# Перенаправление портов на линукс

Tags: linux, сеть, маршрутизация, iptables

Ситуация такая: есть Raspberry за NAT-ом (GSM модем), к нему по LAN подключен даталоггер. Через сервис remot3.it я удаленно получаю доступ к порту "1234" на распбери. Как мне достучаться до даталоггера?

Т.е. мне нужно все пакеты пришедшие на порт 1234 - перенаправить по адресу 192.168.0.255:61234.
Данная команда не помогла.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234-j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.255:61234
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 192.168.0.255 — невозможный адрес для машины, как правило (если только у вас подсеть не /23 и шире).

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev подсеть /22. Изначально даталогер был подключен к сети университета, так и прижилась /22 подсеть.

Comment: а где же *snat*? кому будет отвечать `192.168.0.255`?

Comment: Надо ещё чтобы Raspberry был для datalogger'а default gateway'ем. Ну или как минимум чтобы посылал через raspberry пакеты для того адреса, с которого вы к нему обращаетесь.